# How to print html table without unwanted button and th

Tags: html

[image]

hi im having above table in my html.I want to print table using browser prompt.
the prompt is coming right,But the button on the table is also showing in print preview..How can i remove the unwanted th and buttons.

```
var html = "<html>";
        html += '<style>table, td, th {border:1px; solid black;} td{ textalign:center;}</style>';
        html += '<div style=" border : 3px solid gray ;"><h3 style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;" align="center"><u>Student Academic Details</u></h3>'
                + document.getElementById("studentAcademicGridDiv").innerHTML
                + '</div>';
        html += "</html>";

        var printWin = window
                .open('', '',
                        'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=600,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status  =0');

        printWin.document.write(html);
        printWin.document.close();
        printWin.focus();
        printWin.print();
        printWin.close();
```

I tried above code for printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to `th` and `button` like this: `class="no-print"`

And add this to your CSS:

```
<style media="print">
.no-print {
display: none;
}
<style>
```

I hope this helped you!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in `<style>..</style>`:

```
@media print {
    button, th { display: none; }
}
```